# Trouble centering input in label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap's radio buttons and modifying the style.  I can't seem to get the text on these buttons to vertically center.  I've tried setting the content margin to 0px and setting align-content to center and vertical-align to middle.  Also text-align: center.  What do I do?

Here's the Html:

```
<div class="root">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default active form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" checked autocomplete="off"> One
        </label>

        <label class="btn btn-default form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" autocomplete="off"> Two
        </label>

        <label class="btn btn-default form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" autocomplete="off"> Three
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the css:

```
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

.root .btn-group .btn {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-color: black;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    box-shadow: none;
    min-width: 90px;
    height: 45px;
    align-content: center !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    text-align: center;
}

.root .btn-group .btn .form-check-input {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0px;
}

.root .btn-group .btn.active {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to downvote at least say why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following styles on label

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

```css
 


.root .btn-group .btn {
border-radius: 0;
border-color: black;
background-color: white;
color: black;
box-shadow: none;
min-width: 90px;
height: 45px;
align-content: center !important;
vertical-align: middle !important;
text-align: center;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

.root .btn-group .btn .form-check-input {
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
margin: 0px;
}

.root .btn-group .btn.active {
background-color: black;
color: white;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="root">
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default active form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" checked autocomplete="off"> One
    </label>

    <label class="btn btn-default form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" autocomplete="off"> Two
    </label>

    <label class="btn btn-default form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" autocomplete="off"> Three
    </label>
</div>
</div>
```